# Any way to redirect sd_journal_send to stdout or stderr?

Tags: logging, systemd, syslog

I have some code that uses sd_journal_send() to log to the system logs.  Is there any way to get that to print the messages to stdout or stderr instead.  While I'm running the code for testing purposes, I'd like to avoid it writing to the system logs.

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic linker tricks to fake `sd_journal_sendv`:

```c
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define __USE_GNU

int sd_journal_sendv(const struct iovec *iov, int n) {
  /* send values seperated by newline */
  while (n-- > 0) {
    writev(1, iov+n, 1);//
    write(1,"\n", 1);
  }
}
```

Compile:

```sh
gcc -shared -fPIC  fake_journal.c -o fake_journal.so -ldl
```

Using this sample program:

```c
#include <systemd/sd-journal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  sd_journal_send("MESSAGE=Hello World, this is PID %lu!", (unsigned long) getpid(),
                           "PRIORITY=%i", LOG_INFO,
                           NULL);
}
```

results in this output:

```
LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/fake_journal.so ./test 
PRIORITY=6
MESSAGE=Hello World, this is PID 18772!
CODE_FUNC=main
CODE_LINE=8
CODE_FILE=test.c
```

You can debug the dynamic linker using the [LD_DEBUG](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) environment variable:

```
LD_DEBUG=all LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/fake_journal.so ./test
...
     24082: symbol=sd_journal_sendv;  lookup in file=./test [0]
     24082: symbol=sd_journal_sendv;  lookup in file=/tmp/fake_journal.so [0]
     24082: binding file /usr/lib/libsystemd.so.0 [0] to /tmp/fake_journal.so [0]: normal symbol `sd_journal_sendv' [LIBSYSTEMD_209]
...
```

Comment: Were you able to make this work? For me it still invokes the real sd_journal_sendv.  When resolving a symbol, will the dynamic linker go back (to a pre-loaded library) to find a symbol? That is, in executing sd_journal_send it needs to find sd_journal_sendv, won't it just look in the same (systemd) library?

Comment: Yes, it works for me. I added Info about debugging the dynamic binding using the  `LD_DEBUG` variable.

Comment: Yeah, so it looks like if I call sd_journal_sendv directly from main, it will use my preloaded version, but calling sd_journal_send uses the standard version of sd_journal_sendv.  Is it possible that in compiling the systemd libraries I'm using, the compiler inlined the call to sd_journal_sendv inside of sd_journal_send?

Comment: In any case, I can use the preload trick to provide a dummy implementation of sd_journal_send...