# How to forward systemd logs from a Docker container to the host journalctl?

Tags: c++, docker, systemd

I have an app writing logs to systemd. I would like to run this app in a Docker container and access the logs from host journal system.

The answer is given here but does not work in my case for a unknown reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45701983/2291710

Given the following C++ program:

```cpp
#include <systemd/sd-journal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return sd_journal_send("MESSAGE=Hello World!", "PRIORITY=5", NULL);
}
```

I create a new container and open `bash` while binding `/run/systemd/journal/socket`:

```sh
docker run -v /run/systemd/journal/socket:/run/systemd/journal/socket -v $PWD:/test -it -w /test ubuntu:20.04 bash
```

Then install the dependencies and compile my file from within the container:

```sh
apt-get update && apt-get install -y g++ strace libsystemd-dev
g++ main.cpp -o out -lsystemd
```

But then when I run `./out` nothing show up while I opened `journalctl --user -f` on host. However, if I run `./out` from host, then the expected message is displayed by `journalctl`.

Running `strace` on `./out` from the container or the host demonstrates they are both writing to `/run/systemd/journal/socket`.

Is there any reason for which it would not work?

---

Socket seen from host:

```sh
$ stat /run/systemd/journal/socket 
  File: /run/systemd/journal/socket
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   socket
Device: 19h/25d Inode: 506         Links: 1
Access: (0666/srw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-03-23 13:29:18.401063839 +0100
Modify: 2022-03-21 13:00:06.487999531 +0100
Change: 2022-03-21 13:00:06.487999531 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Socket seen from container:

```sh
# stat /run/systemd/journal/socket 
  File: /run/systemd/journal/socket
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   socket
Device: 19h/25d Inode: 506         Links: 1
Access: (0666/srw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-03-23 12:29:18.401063839 +0000
Modify: 2022-03-21 12:00:06.487999531 +0000
Change: 2022-03-21 12:00:06.487999531 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Using Docker 20.10.12 and not running SELinux.

Using `/run/systemd/journal/` did not work either.

Comment: are you sure the message id is correct?

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Sorry, I could have simplified the snippet. I removed irrelevant parts (including `MESSAGE_ID` which is optional). The issue occurs with a very basic call to `sd_journal_send()` shared above (I tested again).

Comment: i suggest reading [this](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libsystemd-dev/sd_journal_send.3.en.html)  and [this](https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/sd_journal_send/cpp-sd_journal_send-function-examples.html)

Comment: and lastly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617872/any-way-to-redirect-sd-journal-send-to-stdout-or-stderr)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Yeah... Quoting the docs: "If systemd-journald(8) is not running (the socket is not present), those functions do nothing, and also return 0." For sure "journald" isn't running within my container. I'm wondering why the socket binding did the trick in the answer I linked.

Comment: What is the output of `stat /run/systemd/journal/socket` from the container and from host? Do you have selinux running? What version of docker do you use? Please try `-v /run/systemd/journal/:/run/systemd/journal/`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I updated my question with the additional information requested. Do you mean this is working fine on your computer and is an issue on my side only?

Comment: `Do you mean this is working fine on your computer` yes. `while I opened journalctl --user` why did you opened user journalctl? Check the non-user one. Is the host also running ubuntu?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks! I tried on another computer and indeed it worked. I didn't expect this issue to be specific to my configuration. I'll keep investigating it and  make an update if I figure out the solution. I'm watching `--user`, `--system` and default `journalctl` to be sure, but nothing appears in any of them. Both my PC and docker container are running Ubuntu 20.04.